# How to get the first 8-digit CUSIP (compustat database) using Python?

Tags: python, string

I get the CUSIP data from COMPUSTAT database. CUSIP here is 9-digit and I want to extract the first 8-digit of it. However, when I tried the following code, the output is very weird.

For example, for CUSIP = 000032102 (data type is object), I obtain the following: 
0    000032102
1    000032102
2    000032102
3    000032102
4    000032102
5    000032102
6    000032102
7    000032102
Name: cusip2, dtype: object

This is essentially the first 8 rows of 'CUSIP' column, rather than the first 8-digit of each CUSIP number. What should I do to get the first 8-digit of CUSIP. Many thanks!

```
df['cusip2'] = df['cusip'].astype(str)
df['cusip2'] = str(df['cusip2'][:8])
```

Comment: Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are going to get better results if you follow hints present on those articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `str` [accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#accessors), which allows you to map operations over each element, as a string, in a column:

```
df['cusip2'].astype(str).str[:8]
```